# Unable to create a many to many relationship using sequelize for mysql in nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to create a relationship between 2 tables by having a junction table for the same, here is schema for my tables

`Site Table`

| siteId | siteName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |

`Customer Table`

| customerId | customerName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | x |
| 2 | y |

Here, a site can have more than 1 customer who belongs to it, and a customer may belong to more than 1 site.
So i have created another table :-
`site_customer`

| scId | siteId | customerId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 |

Here is my code for models:-

`Site.js model`

```
module.exports = function ({ sequelize, DataTypes }) {
  const Site = sequelize.define(
    "Site",
    {
      siteId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
          notEmpty: true,
        },
        primaryKey: true,
      },
      siteName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(20),
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
          notEmpty: true,
        },
      },
    },
    {
      timestamps: false,
    },
    {
      tableName: "sites",
    }
  );
  return Site;
};
```

`Customer.js Model`

```
module.exports = function ({ sequelize, DataTypes, Site }) {
  console.log(Site);
  const Customer = sequelize.define(
    "customers",
    {
      customerId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
          notEmpty: true,
        },
        primaryKey: true,
      },
      customerName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
          notEmpty: true,
        },
      },
    },
    {
      timestamps: false,
    },
    {
      tableName: "customers",
    }
  );
  return Customer;
};
```

`SiteCustomer.js model`

```
module.exports = ({ sequelize, DataTypes, Site, Customer }) => {
  const SiteCustomer = sequelize.define(
    "site_customer",
    {
      scId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
          notEmpty: true,
        },
      },
      siteId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: Site,
          key: "siteId",
        },
        onDelete: "cascade",
        onUpdate: "cascade",
      },
      customerId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: Customer,
          key: "customerId",
        },
        onDelete: "cascade",
        onUpdate: "cascade",
      },
    },
    {
      timestamps: false,
    },
    {
      tableName: "site_customer",
    },
    {
      indexes: [
        {
          unique: true,
          fields: ["siteId", "customerId"],
        },
      ],
    }
  );

  return SiteCustomer;
};
```

The above code generates all three tables as desired but, when in my `index.js` file in `models` folder i associate the models like this:-

```
const db = {};

db.DataTypes = DataTypes;
db.sequelize = sequelize;

db.Site = require("./Site")(db);
db.Customer = require("./Customers")(db);
db.SiteCustomer = require("./SiteCustomer")(db);

db.Site.belongsToMany(db.Customer, { through: db.SiteCustomer });
db.Customer.belongsToMany(db.Site, { through: db.SiteCustomer });
```

This code creates 2 more columns in the table named : `SiteSiteId` & `customerCustomerId` but i don't need those columns as i have already added `siteId` & `customerId` in `site_customer` table while creating the model.

[image]

I do not want the extra 2 columns at the end.
Any help for the same will be highly appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove references from the pivot model `SiteCustomer.js`, as given as under

```
  `siteId: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    onDelete: "cascade",
    onUpdate: "cascade",
  },
  customerId: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    onDelete: "cascade",
    onUpdate: "cascade",
  },`
```

It might help.